# Mysql-PHP how to separate long string row into different columns?

Tags: php, mysql

Roan

I am currently looking into spliting a long row,from table1 and insert in multiple columns in another table2, the string the values are separated by a "/" and "-". 
is there a way to split a cell values at the occurrence of the "/" or "-" and insert in to the existing table2 in their separate columns?

I've a table with entries like this.

To turn this: table1

  id   value

  1   FO910/test123/KO9200-7890/asdasd23423/ ...

  2    ML45/uj890-892ht/kjsl923023/sdsds-wer3434 ..

into this: table2

  id   value1   value2 ...

  1   F0910    test123

  2    ML45     UJ890

any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: Why do you put the data originally in so inconvenient way? The better would be to put it in different columns initially

Comment: If it worked don't forget to choose the answer by clicking the checkmark

Comment: in that way populated in the table from radio signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$data= "FO910/test123/KO9200-7890/asdasd23423"

$row = preg_split("/[\/\-]/", $data);
/* example output
array(1)
(
    [0] => string(5) "FO910"
    [1] => string(7) "test123"
    [2] => string(6) "KO9200"
    [3] => string(4) "7890"
    [4] => string(12) "asdasd23423"
) */

foreach($col in $row )
{ 
   echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>';
}
```

Comment: he wants the dash to split values as well, so the values should be FO910, test123, KO9200, 7890, asdasd23423. Do `$data = str_replace('-','/',$data);`
 before the explode part.

Comment: preg_split can do the same thing with regex